# Does sheafification preserve flasqueness?

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

(I feel like the following question is probably something really basic. Oh, well.)

Recall that a sheaf $F$ on a topological space $X$ is *flasque* if for every open subset $U\subseteq X$, the restriction map $F(X)\to F(U)$ is surjective. Since this definition doesn't use the sheaf axioms, we can also use it to define flasqueness for presheaves.

My question is then: If $F$ is a flasque presheaf, is its sheafification $F^+$ also flasque?

Comment: No, take for example the constant presheaf (obviously flasque), its sheafification is the constant sheaf which is not flasque.

Comment: @Roland See! I knew it was basic. :P You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, take for example the constant presheaf (obviously flasque), its sheafification is the constant sheaf which is not flasque in general (and in fact has very interesting cohomology).